# Clear inherited :before css

Tags: html, css

I've got a nested ul-list where I use the :before-selector to apply some background-image and content. I'd like to clear this on the deeper-level ul's. How can I do this?

Setting `background: none` still make the image appear. The odd thing is that it only happens on the first element.

CSS:

```
.sidemeny ul li:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    background: transparent url('gfx/mer.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Try this: '.sidemeny ul > li:before'

Comment: Seems like a specificity problem. Please post the code you used to try to remove the background. PS; you could also use `content:none` to remove the entire pseudo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sidemeny ul li li:before{display:none}
```